# how to read attributes of an element in xml file using objective c?

Tags: xml, xcode

In my application am getting an xml file from server and in that i have some attributes for the element.i donno how to read the attributes .The following is my XML file

```
 <History> 
    <Result ImageId="4507" Description="" Date="10/19/2010 12:49:22 AM" />
    <Result ImageId="4505" Description="" Date="10/18/2010 8:01:28 AM" />
 </History>
```

so i want to assign ImageId,Description and Date into three variables and i want to save each result into an array.
Reading data from that array.Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard iPhone way

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingParser.html

[Handling XML Elements and Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-BCIJFGJI)

another way to parse [Using libxml2 for XML parsing and XPath queries in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html)

I know there are third party libraries that simplify the process

Comment: i have gone through the above things but i did not find any solution for my problem.Can you please explain it for my above XML file

Comment: @iphoneStruggler what have you written so far? Post the errors and maybe you will get a response.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are going to store the attribute values into NSStrings.

```
NSString *ImageId;
NSString *Description;
NSString *Date;

you can use simple if statements.
if([Elementname isEqualToString:@"Result"]){
  ImageId = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"ImageId"];
  Description = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Description"];
  Date = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Date"];
}
```

So as you can see first you have to decide which element you are interested in which  your case would be the "Result" element. Then you are telling the compiler that if the elementname is "Result" you want its attribute values stores under ImageId, Description & Date to be saved into NSStrings.